# VSCODE: No module named spotipy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, spotipy, modulenotfounderror

I am using VSCode and trying to import spotipy.
I have:
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
I keep getting the error that "no module named spotipy". However, I have done pip install spotipy and pip3 install spotipy. I even did an anacanda version all in the terminal of VSCode. When I do "pip list", it says that it spotipy 2.18.0 is installed.

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: check your VSCode interpreter.  Make sure it matches the Python installation where you installed that package

Comment: Indeed. If it isn't installed, you can set up a `virtualenv` and use `pip` to install again. Make sure you activate it!

Comment: If you get the error when running your code, see [Using Python Environments in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments). If you get it from the linter/Problems tab, configure your linter to find your Python environment.